# Embed Youtube channel into Flash Site

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, youtube, embed

How can i embed a Youtube channel to a Flash site?, is it posible using ActionScript3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the API provided by YouTube to embed youtube channels:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference